# Interference in decibles

Tags: interference

A is transmitting a signal to point B . But in this process A is creating an interference at point C. So if the distance between point A and point C decreases the interference will increase. My question is if the value of pathloss between point A and C changes from -10dbm to -30dbm , the interference will increase or it will decrease. (The value in watts will change from 0.0001 to 0.000001 respectively)

Comment: okay so i tried to figure it out and as the value changes from -10dBm to -30dBm; the interference will decrease as the distance increases

Comment: If point B is receiving the signal, then what you should consider is the distance between point C and point B. You could actually move the interference source closer to the transmitter and get less interference power at the receiver. Think about the interference being at the mid-point between the transmitter and receiver and now move the interference towards the transmitter (away from receiver)